# Send email using VBA when combination of cell vaues is true

Tags: excel, vba, email, cell, onchange

My sheet 'Volglijst' contains a list with all packages that have been registerd for sending. 
When the package is picked up by the supplier or courrier, the goods reception service registers the date and who picked up the package.

When they close the file, a pop-up appears that is asking if they want to send e-mail confirmation to the person who requested the sending. 
When they select yes VBA should check all rows in sheet 'Volglijst' where there is a date in Column B and Column Q, and where column S is empty (the 3 conditions should apply at the same time, if not, no e-mail needs to be send).

I'm getting my outlook to start and create a new e-mail, but it remains empty.
The body is working for an other e-mail only the reference to the cell content is adjusted to match the rows for which the conditions apply.

```
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim i As Long
Dim t As Range
Dim WkSht As Worksheet
Dim strbody As String
Set WkSht = Sheets("Volglijst")

For i = 1 To 999
If WkSht.Cells(i, 2).Value <> "" And WkSht.Cells(i, 17).Value <> "" And WkSht.Cells(i, 19).Value = "" Then
Dim rng As Range
With Application.Intersect(WkSht.Rows(i), WkSht.UsedRange)
    Set rng = WkSht.Range(WkSht.Cells(i, 3), .Cells(.Cells.Count))
         End With

If rng Is Nothing Then
Exit Sub
End If
End If
Next
On Error Resume Next

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

strbody = "<font size=""3"" face=""Calibri"">" & _
"Beste Collega,<br><br>" & _
"Uw pakket met nummer <B>" & WkSht.Cells(WkSht.Rows(i), 1).Value & "</B> werd <B>" & WkSht.Cells(WkSht.Rows(i), 17).Value & "</B> opgehaald door <B>" & WkSht.Cells(WkSht.Rows(i), 16).Value & "</B>.<br>" & _
"Bijkomende opmerkingen goederenontvangst: <B>" & WS.Cells(WkSht.Rows(i), 18).Value & "</B>.<br>" & _
"<br><br>In geval van vragen gelieve contact op te nemen." & _
"<br><br> Met vriendelijke groeten, </font>"
On Error Resume Next


With OutMail
.To = WS.Cells(WkSht.Rows(i), 5).Value
.CC = ""
.BCC = ""
.Subject = "Ophaling pakket " & WS.Cells(i, 1).Value & ""
.HTMLBody = strbody
.Display  'or use .Send
End With
```

A separate email sould be sent for each row with column B <> ""; column Q <> "", Column S = "" , and the recepient is the e-mail adres of column E in that row. Details in the email body should also come from the applicable row.

Comment: Comment out `On Error Resume Next` - do you get an error and what is the error message?

Comment: Also, you haven't mentioned what the issue is?

Comment: I would *highly* recommend compartmentalizing this, where one subroutine contrains Excel activities and a separate for Outlook activities; this will help in overall troubleshooting.  Set ranges, or save the values in variables to be utilized in the email, where possible, as this prevents having to go back and forth between the two applications.

Comment: @ Zac, the email is empty the data is not loaded

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following is what you are looking for, this will loop from Row 1 to the last in the UsedRange, check whether Columns B & Q are not empty and Column S is empty then deal with the email per row:

```
Sub LoopThroughRange_SendEmail()
Dim OutApp As Object: Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Dim OutMail As Object: Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
Dim i As Long
Dim strbody As String
Dim WkSht As Worksheet: Set WkSht = Sheets("Volglijst")

For i = 1 To WkSht.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    If WkSht.Cells(i, "B").Value <> "" And WkSht.Cells(i, "Q").Value <> "" And WkSht.Cells(i, "S").Value = "" Then
        strbody = "<html><body><font size=""3"" face=""Calibri"">Beste Collega,<br><br>Uw pakket met nummer <b>" & _
        WkSht.Cells(i, "A").Value & "</b> werd <b>" & WkSht.Cells(i, "Q").Value & "</b> opgehaald door <b>" & _
        WkSht.Cells(i, "P").Value & "</b>.<br>Bijkomende opmerkingen goederenontvangst: <b>" & _
        WkSht.Cells(i, "R").Value & "</B>.<br><br><br>In geval van vragen gelieve contact op te nemen.<br><br>" & _
        "Met vriendelijke groeten, </font></body></html>"

    With OutMail
        .To = WkSht.Cells(i, "E").Value
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Ophaling pakket " & WkSht.Cells(i, "A").Value & ""
        .HTMLBody = strbody
        .Display  'or use .Send
    End With

    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

**UPDATE:**

To also validate the email address before attempting to send the email, the below will help, it will allow multiple email addresses in a single cells separated by a ;

```
Sub LoopThroughRange_SendEmail()
Dim oRegEx As Object
Set oRegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
Dim OutApp As Object: Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Dim OutMail As Object: Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
Dim i As Long
Dim strbody As String
Dim WkSht As Worksheet: Set WkSht = Sheets("Volglijst")

For i = 1 To WkSht.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    If ValidEmail(WkSht.Cells(i, "E").Value, oRegEx) Then
        If WkSht.Cells(i, "B").Value <> "" And WkSht.Cells(i, "Q").Value <> "" And WkSht.Cells(i, "S").Value = "" Then
            strbody = "<html><body><font size=""3"" face=""Calibri"">Beste Collega,<br><br>Uw pakket met nummer <b>" & _
            WkSht.Cells(i, "A").Value & "</b> werd <b>" & WkSht.Cells(i, "Q").Value & "</b> opgehaald door <b>" & _
            WkSht.Cells(i, "P").Value & "</b>.<br>Bijkomende opmerkingen goederenontvangst: <b>" & _
            WkSht.Cells(i, "R").Value & "</B>.<br><br><br>In geval van vragen gelieve contact op te nemen.<br><br>" & _
            "Met vriendelijke groeten, </font></body></html>"

            With OutMail
                .To = WkSht.Cells(i, "E").Value
                .CC = ""
                .BCC = ""
                .Subject = "Ophaling pakket " & WkSht.Cells(i, "A").Value & ""
                .HTMLBody = strbody
                .Display  'or use .Send
            End With
        End If
    Else
        'email address is not valid
    End If
Next i
End Sub

Public Function ValidEmail(pAddress As String, ByRef oRegEx As Object) As Boolean
    With oRegEx
        .Pattern = "^(([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.\']+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)(\s*;\s*|\s*$))+$" 'pattern for multiple email addresses included
        ValidEmail = .test(pAddress)
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: This is indeed what I'm looking for. The email is properly created and populated, yet only for the last item with the specified criteria. 
I can see that the initial email is created for the 1st item that meets the criteria, but updated by any next one. 
How can I get it to send an email for each item that meets the criteria?

Comment: The For Loop will go through each Row, while the IF statement will check that the row actually meets the criteria, then the email is generated using values from that given Row,.... Isn't that what you were looking for? Or do you mean that the values for the email body should be taken only from the first row that meets the criteria?

Comment: It indeed is looping through each row and creating an e-mail for each row that meets the criteria, but the same e-mail is updated with information of the next row that meets the criteria and only sending it for the last row. Instead it should send the e-mail for the first hit, then go look for the next hit and create another e-mail. If it helps a text can be put in column S before goning to the next row so it will not hit the same row after sending the e-mail (I now have this at the end). I'm sorry if I'm asking for basic things,  I'm really new at this. Anyhow thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @user12187248 did you try to amend the line `.Display  'or use .Send` to use `.Send` instead of `.Display`?

Comment: Hi Xabier, yes I did and only for the last item that meets the criteria it is sending an email.
I'll create a workaround where they have to click a command button after completing a form per package that has been picked up. The macro will then complete the follow up file (Volglijst) and send the required email before clearing the form and asking if they want to register another package.

Answer (score 0):

Will attempt to compartmentalize this, but you have a couple significant issue:

- You utilize `i` in the outlook aspect of this email OUTSIDE of the loop, so you're just using `i = 999`, or was this intended to be within the loop?
- The references in your `strbody` were to different worksheets... check your references.  I called out the first occurrence in the `Excel_Activities` subroutine when I started defining each use.

---

```
Public bdy_a as string, bdy_b as string, bdy_c as string, bdy_d as string
Public to_ as string
Public sub_ as string
'
Sub Excel_Activities()
    Dim i as Long, t As Range
    Dim WkSht As Worksheet
    Dim strbody As String
    Set WkSht = Sheets("Volglijst")
    For i = 1 To 999
        If WkSht.Cells(i, 2).Value <> "" And WkSht.Cells(i, 17).Value <> "" And WkSht.Cells(i, 19).Value = "" Then
            Dim rng As Range
            With Application.Intersect(WkSht.Rows(i), WkSht.UsedRange)
                Set rng = WkSht.Range(WkSht.Cells(i, 3), .Cells(.Cells.Count))
            End With
            If rng Is Nothing Then
                Exit Sub
            Else
                bdy_a = WkSht.Cells(i, 1).Value
                bdy_b = WkSht.Cells(i, 17).Value
                bdy_c = WkSht.Cells(i, 16).Value
                bdy_d = WS.Cells(i, 18).Value 'IS THIS CORRECT SHEET?
                to_ = WS.Cells(WkSht.Rows(i), 5).Value
                sub_ = WS.Cells(i, 1).Value
                Application.Run("Outlook_Activities")
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Then deal with the saved values to create the desired email, which appears to occur within the `Loop` based on the use of `i` in your original post `strbody`.

```
Private Sub Outlook_Activities()
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    strbody = "<font size=""3"" face=""Calibri"">" & "Beste Collega,<br><br>" & "Uw pakket met nummer <B>" & bdy_a & "</B> werd <B>" & bdy_b & "</B> opgehaald door <B>" & bdy_c & "</B>.<br>" & "Bijkomende opmerkingen goederenontvangst: <B>" &  & "</B>.<br>" & "<br><br>In geval van vragen gelieve contact op te nemen." & "<br><br> Met vriendelijke groeten, </font>"

    With OutMail
        .To = to_
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Ophaling pakket " & sub_ & ""
        .HTMLBody = strbody
        .Display  'or use .Send
    End With
End Sub
```